# How could I load a page with parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, url, get

I'm working on a blog project(learning course) which shows the bills of trains and comments associated. It's working with GET parameters.

I made every improvments ask by the professor except the one where I have to load the blog with parameters on url. There below you have a screenshot  it's show undefined index and it's fine but I don't know how to load it with parameters :

Cpt1:
[image: Cpt1]

I try with include but I don't have others file to load with I made all improvments in same page and with empty fonction() too but after I don't know how to make it ( I'm beginner).

I'm not asking the answer but If you have any hint to help to deal with or If it's too complex give me an explanation please ! ( Sorry for If my english is bad  I'm not native one)

The code :

```html
<?php 
include('connexion.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mon super Blog !</h1>
    <p>Derniers billets du blog : </p>



    <!-- NEWS -->
    <div class="news">
        
        
        <?php
        
        $recuperation_titre_du_billets_et_contenu = $bdd->query("SELECT Id,Titre,Contenu,DATE_FORMAT(Date_creation,'%d/%m/%Y à %H:%i') AS date_affiché FROM billets LIMIT 0,4");
        while($données = $recuperation_titre_du_billets_et_contenu->fetch())
        {
            echo "<h3>".htmlspecialchars($données['Titre'])." le ".htmlspecialchars($données['date_affiché'])."</h3>";
            
            ?>
            <p>
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($données['Contenu']);
            ?>
            
            <a href="commentaires.php?Id_billet=<? echo $données['Id']?>&amp;page_commentaire=1">Commentaires</a>
            
        </p>
        
        <?php 
        }
        $recuperation_titre_du_billets_et_contenu->closeCursor();
        ?>

</div>
<!-- FIN NEWS -->

<!-- NEWS2 -->

<div class="news2">
    
    <?php
                    
                    $billetsdelapage2 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT Id,Titre,Contenu,DATE_FORMAT(Date_creation,'%d/%m/%Y à %H:%i') AS date_affiché FROM billets LIMIT 4,4");
                    $billetsdelapage2->execute(array($_GET['page']));
                    
                    if(isset($_GET['page']) == 2)
                    {
                        while($data = $billetsdelapage2->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<h3>".htmlspecialchars($data['Titre'])." le ".htmlspecialchars($data['date_affiché'])."</h3>";
                            ?>
                                      <p>
                                          <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['Contenu']);
                                                ?>
                                                <a href="commentaires.php?Id_billet=<? echo $data['Id'];?>">Commentaires</a>
                                                <?php
                        }
                        ?>

<style>    
                                                    .news
                                                    {
                                                        display:none;
                                                    }
                                                    </style>


</p>
<?
                                    }
                                    $billetsdelapage2->closeCursor();       
                                    ?>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <!-- FIN NEWS2 -->  

                                <!-- NEWS3 -->
                                <div class="news3">
                                    
                                    <?php
                    
                    $billetsdelapage3 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT Id,Titre,Contenu,DATE_FORMAT(Date_creation,'%d/%m/%Y à %H:%i') AS date_affiché FROM billets LIMIT 8,12");
                    $billetsdelapage3->execute(array($_GET['page']));
                    
                    if(isset($_GET['page']) AND ($_GET['page'] != 2 ))
                    {
                        while($data = $billetsdelapage3->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<h3>".htmlspecialchars($data['Titre'])." le ".htmlspecialchars($data['date_affiché'])."</h3>";
                            ?>
                                      <p>
                                          <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['Contenu']);
                        ?>
                        <a href="commentaires.php?Id_billet=<? echo $data['Id']?>">Commentaires</a>
                        <?
                    }
                    ?>
                                                    <style>    
                                                    .news
                                                    {
                                                        display:none;
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    .news2{
                                                        display:none;
                                                    }
                                                    </style>

</p>
<?
                                    }
                                    $billetsdelapage3->closeCursor();       
                                    ?>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <!-- FIN NEWS3 -->
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="pagination">
                                <!-- Petite erreur qui sera rectifié plus tard vis à vis des numéros de page  ! -->
                                <a href="index.php">1</a>
                                <a href="index.php?page=2">2</a>
                                <a href="index.php?page=3">3</a>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show the code please

Comment: I put the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to get a parameter from the URL like:

`HTTP://myurl.com/index.php?myParameter=10`

Then using something like this should work.

```php
if (isset($_GET['page'])){ //check to see if 'page' is set.
$pageNo= $_GET['page']; //then set a variable equal to the parameter.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
On my url its written :
http://localhost/PHP/Blog/
but what I need is when the page load it's go on :
http://localhost/PHP/Blog/index.php?page=2

I don't know if I enough clear or should I rephrase it  ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? from your code, it looks like you have already created links that should take you to the correct URL and then you would use the above code to grab the page number and then from there you can do what you want with it.

Comment: You're right the fact is I got lost on my way... I understood the instruction like if I have others page( page1.php,page2.php,etc...) then I could use an include to load a default page with ( index.php) then I could navigate through others pages with my links below and my problem would be resolved. I've done the project without them just by using GET parameter.

Comment: At the end I was so stubborn about the instruction that I confuse my self.
Now it's clear so thanks you !